# Splitting a JavaScript string from XML and wrapping in HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I'm working on displaying an RSS feed in a website through the use of jQuery and AJAX. One of the strings from the source XML file are wrapped in a `<category>` tag, and there are multiple of these returned. I'm getting the source data like follows:

```
        var _category = $(this).find('category').text();
```

Because there are multiple categories returned with this method, say the following:

```
<category>Travel</category>
<category>Business</category>
<category>Lifestyle</category>
```

I'm getting strings returned like so:

```
TravelBusinessLifestyle
```

My end goal is to see each of these separate strings returned and wrapped in individual HTML elements, such as `<div class="new"></div>`.

I did end up trying the following:

```
    var _categoryContainer = $(this)
    .find('category')
    .each(function () {
      $(this).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
    });
```

among quite a few other variations.

This is all being appended to a HTML structure similar to the following.

```
        // Add XML content to the HTML structure
        $(".rss .rss-loader")
          .append(
            '<div class="col">'
            + <h5 class="myClass">myTitle</h5>
            + _category
            + "</div>"
          );
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the output - if it's add to the html, then you just need to add `.appendTo()`:  `$(this).wrap("<div>").appendTo("#output");`

Comment: Not an issue appending to the HTML - my issue is with splitting the source strings. Updated my question to reflect how it's being appended.

Comment: So append as you split, using your code.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if it's a simple html which is mentioned in a question. you can use something like below.

```js
var html="<category>Travel</category><category>Business</category><category>Lifestyle</category>"
var htmlObj=$.parseHTML(html);
var container=$("#container")
$.each(htmlObj,function(i,o){
   container.append("<div class='new'>"+o.innerText+"</div>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as first answer, but without jquery

```js
let container = document.querySelector('div#container');
document.querySelectorAll('category').forEach(element => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = element.innerText;
  container.appendChild(div);
})
```

```html
<category>Travel</category><category>Business</category><category>Lifestyle</category>

<div id="container"></div>
```